# How to draw several lines with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code draws 2 lines

```
dd = list(data.frame(rates=1:5), data.frame(rates=2:6), data.frame(rates=3:7))
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
g = ggplot(, aes(1:5))
g <- g + geom_line(aes(y = dd[[1]]$rate[index(dd[[1]]) <= 5]), colour="#000000")
g <- g + geom_line(aes(y = dd[[2]]$rate[index(dd[[2]]) <= 5]), colour="#000000")
g
```

[image]

But this code draws 1 line (for last i, 2)

```
dd = list(data.frame(rates=1:5), data.frame(rates=2:6), data.frame(rates=3:7))
g = ggplot(, aes(1:5))
foreach (i = 1:2) %do% {
  g <- g + geom_line(aes(y = dd[[i]]$rate[index(dd[[i]]) <= 5]), colour="#000000")
}
g
```

[image]

Example on [r-fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=SNYtB0Hz&version=2)

Why and how to fix?

Comment: What does your data look like? What does the plot look like? `dd` seems to be a list of `data.frames`, with a column called `val`. Can you share some of your data so that we can run your code?

Comment: Edited, i hope you help

Comment: Do you really need to build your graphs in parallel? More generally, your use of ggplot is extremely non-standard. You might get more mileage out of using ggplot more in line with the way it was intended.

Comment: ...also your example still isn't reproducible. I think there is probably a **zoo** dependency lurking in there somewhere.

Comment: Ok, here is reproducible example on r-fiddle, any idea?: http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=SNYtB0Hz&version=2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I alluded to, I think you should simply stop using **ggplot2** so strangely:

```
g = ggplot(, aes(1:5))
foreach (i = 1:2) %do% {
  g <- g + geom_line(data = dd[[i]],aes(y = rates), colour="#000000")
}
g
```

This produces two lines just like your first example.